# using File.Move to copy file from source folder to destination folder changes my file owner

Tags: vb.net, file, windows-services

I am moving files from source folder to destination folder using File.Move, when  files got moved to destination folder file owner name is getting changed to Administrator instead of original user I tried below code but unable to set file owner in destination folder. My application is a windows service

My Code:

```
Dim fOwner = File.GetAccessControl(srcFolder + "\" + srcFileName).GetOwner(GetType(System.Security.Principal.SecurityIdentifier))
```

After Moving file I am setting it to original owner

```
File.GetAccessControl(destFolder + "\" + destFileName).SetOwner(fOwner)
```

but it still shows owner as administrator. Tried lot of examples but no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to also call `SetAccessControl` to apply the owner change. Try something like this:

```
Dim fs as FileSecurity = File.GetAccessControl(Path.Combine(destFolder, destFileName))
fs.SetOwner(fOwner)
File.SetAccessControl(Path.Combine(destFolder, destFileName),fs)
```